# Can't initialize mediaCapture UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-recording, mediacapture

I'm using Windows.Media.Capture lib to capture audio from the default microphone of the laptop,

The problem is that i can't initialize the mediaCapture object it display : "The parameter is incorrect" 
I used the InitializeAsync method with and without settings but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue please!

Thanks,

Comment: The debugger should also tell you which parameter is incorrect, right?

Comment: the problem is even when i use the InitializeAsync without any parameter, so it Initialize the mediacapture with default settings, i have the same exception and the same message.

Comment: What is the OS build version? And what is the target/min version in the project settings?

Comment: To understand whether it is a coding issue or a device issue, try download and run the official sample from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit). If you cannot use even this sample, then maybe you have to check whether the driver is the latest. And do you have any other camera device which can be used for test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add capabilities for Microphone and the WebCam even if you just want to do an audio record,

Thanks guys for your replies